# Lightbox fslightbox issue, transparent background instead of white

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, lightbox

I am using Lightbox fslightbox https://github.com/banthagroup/fslightbox And I have a problem with the background. I am trying set up a white background color but in some computer it shows white and other transparent.

Can you help me to check with place of the code I need modificative? I leave you the css (it is coming integrate with the js)

````
.fslightbox-absoluted{position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
.fslightbox-fade-in{animation:fslightbox-fade-in .25s cubic-bezier(0,0,.7,1)}
.fslightbox-fade-out{animation:fslightbox-fade-out .25s ease}
.fslightbox-fade-in-strong{animation:fslightbox-fade-in-strong .25s cubic-bezier(0,0,.7,1)}
.fslightbox-fade-out-strong{animation:fslightbox-fade-out-strong .25s ease}
@keyframes fslightbox-fade in{from{opacity:.65}to{opacity:1}}@keyframes fslightbox-fade-out{from{opacity:.35}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes fslightbox-fade-in-strong{from{opacity:.3}to{opacity:1}}@keyframes fslightbox-fade-out-strong{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}
.fslightbox-cursor-grabbing{cursor:grabbing}
.fslightbox-full-dimension{width:100%;height:100%}
.fslightbox-open{overflow:hidden;height:100%}
.fslightbox-flex-centered{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center}
.fslightbox-opacity-0{opacity:0!important}
.fslightbox-opacity-1{opacity:1!important}
.fslightbox-scrollbarfix{padding-right:17px}
.fslightbox-transform-transition{transition:transform .3s}
.fslightbox-container{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background:rgba(255,255,255);z-index:1000000000;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}
.fslightbox-container *{box-sizing:border-box}
.fslightbox-svg-path{transition:fill .15s ease;fill:#615E5D}
.fslightbox-nav{height:45px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
.fslightbox-slide-number-container{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;position:relative;height:100%;font-size:15px;color:#615E5D;z-index:0;max-width:55px;text-align:left}
.fslightbox-slide-number-container .fslightbox-flex-centered{height:100%}
.fslightbox-slash{display:block;margin:0 5px;width:1px;height:12px;transform:rotate(15deg);background:#615E5D}.fslightbox-toolbar{position:absolute;z-index:3;right:0;top:0;height:100%;display:flex;background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.1)}
.fslightbox-toolbar-button{height:100%;width:45px;cursor:pointer}
.fslightbox-toolbar-button:hover 
.fslightbox-svg-path{fill:#d7d7d7}
.fslightbox-slide-btn-container{display:flex;align-items:center;padding:12px 12px 12px 6px;position:absolute;top:50%;cursor:pointer;z-index:3;transform:translateY(-50%)}@media (min-width:476px){.fslightbox-slide-btn-container{padding:22px 22px 22px 6px}}@media (min-width:768px){.fslightbox-slide-btn-container{padding:30px 30px 30px 6px}}
.fslightbox-slide-btn-container:hover .fslightbox-svg-path{fill:#d7d7d7}
.fslightbox-slide-btn{padding:9px;font-size:26px;background:gba(255,255,255, 0.1)}@media (min-width:768px){.fslightbox-slide-btn{padding:10px}}@media (min-width:1600px){.fslightbox-slide-btn{padding:11px}}
.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-previous{left:0}@media (max-width:475.99px){.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-previous{padding-left:3px}}
.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-next{right:0;padding-left:12px;padding-right:3px}@media (min-width:476px){.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-next{padding-left:22px}}@media (min-width:768px){.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-next{padding-left:30px}}@media (min-width:476px){.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-next{padding-right:6px}}
.fslightbox-down-event-detector{position:absolute;z-index:1}
.fslightbox-slide-swiping-hoverer{z-index:4}
.fslightbox-invalid-file-wrapper{font-size:22px;color:#eaebeb;margin:auto}
.fslightbox-video{object-fit:cover}.fslightbox-youtube-iframe{border:0}
.fslightbox-loader{display:block;margin:auto;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);width:67px;height:67px}
.fslightbox-loader div{box-sizing:border-box;display:block;position:absolute;width:54px;height:54px;margin:6px;border:5px solid;border-color:#999 transparent transparent transparent;border-radius:50%;animation:fslightbox-loader 1.2s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.5,1) infinite}
.fslightbox-loader div:nth-child(1){animation-delay:-.45s}
.fslightbox-loader div:nth-child(2){animation-delay:-.3s}
.fslightbox-loader div:nth-child(3){animation-delay:-.15s}@keyframes fslightbox-loader{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}
.fslightbox-source{position:relative;z-index:2;opacity:0} ```

Thanks
````

Comment: Super hyper scroll x man... You really should format that line of code my friend! Make it easier for people to help you!

Comment: Sorry, it was coming inside of the js file in that way. I modified it, hopefully it is correct

Comment: I recommend looking for an alternative, such as https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/